# Using the postgres image in a test

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Given the following docker-compose.test.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  sut:
    build: .
    command: nosetests
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=test.settings
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
```

Building the sut container

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml build sut
```

Running the container:

```
thomas@linuxclientlobnek01:~/github/djlobnek$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run sut /bin/bash 
root@6694ec7148ac:/djlobnek# psql -h localhost -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
**could not connect to server: Connection refused**
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your application is attempting to connect to the database before the database is ready to accept connections.  If this is the case, then implementing some sort of wait-for-the-database loop into the `sut` container can resolve the problem.  I have in the past used something like:

```
while ! psql -h db -U postgres postgres -c 'select 1'; do
  echo "waiting for database"
  sleep 1
done
```

This is unnecessary if your application knows how to retry unsuccessful database connections.

Before you try this, it's a good idea to verify that the postgres container is actually functioning (e.g., by entering the `sut` container with `docker exec` and attempting to manually connect using `psql`).

**Update**

Trying to connect to `localhost` from inside the `sut` container won't work (postgres isn't run inside that container).  You would need to use the hostname `db`, or you would need to the ip address of the `db` container.  E.g:

```
postgres -h db -U postgres postgres
```

You could use `localhost` as the hostname if you `docker exec` into the `db` container itself.

Comment: I connect directly into the sut layer using {docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run sut /bin/bash}. I have installed the postgresql-client in the dockerfile. Running {psql -h localhost -U postgres} is not successful

Comment: Indeed, learnt the localhost issue. I can indeed connect now to the container and once in I can use psql to start the postgres command line, e.g. thomas@linuxclientlobnek01:~/github/djlobnek$ docker-compose -p test -f docker-compose.test.yml run sut /bin/bash

root@245ad3d10a9b:/djlobnek# psql -h db -U postgres   THAT WORKS, however...

Comment: Of course, the point is to automate this and here I still face problems. So notice how similar my command is: docker-compose -p test -f docker-compose.test.yml run sut. Here the tests fail with the same aforementioned refused connection

Comment: ...at which point I refer you to the first part of my answer, in which I postulate that what you are seeing is a timing issue for which there is, fortunately, a simple solution.